# QThread связь окна с потоком

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Есть код, какой метод прописать, что бы была связь потока и окна?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QFrame, QApplication, QLabel

class Thread(QThread):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

def run(self):

    pos = True
    while pos:
        if self.frame.pos().x() == 50 and self.frame.pos().y() == 180:
            print('Complete')
        else:
            print('Error')

class Window(QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.InitWindow()

    self.thread = Thread()
    self.thread.start()

def InitWindow(self):

    self.resize(500, 500)

    self.frame = QFrame(self)
    self.frame.resize(100, 100)
    self.frame.move(50, 180)
    self.frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: black')
    self.x, self.y = self.frame.pos().x(), self.frame.pos().y()

    self.text = "x: {0},  y: {1}".format(self.x, self.y)
    self.label = QLabel(self.text, self)
    self.label.setGeometry(50, 0, 100, 100)

def keyPressEvent(self, e):

    if e.key() == Qt.Key_Down:
        self.y += 10
    elif e.key() == Qt.Key_Up:
        self.y -= 10
    elif e.key() == Qt.Key_Right:
        self.x += 10
    elif e.key() == Qt.Key_Left:
        self.x -= 10

    self.frame.move(self.x, self.y)
    self.text = "x: {0},  y: {1}".format(self.x, self.y)
    self.label.setText(self.text)

if __name__=="__main__":

app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте это.

Тут в поток передана ссылка на виджет и в функции проверки добавил небольшую задержку:

```
import time
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QFrame, QApplication, QLabel


class Thread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        super().__init__()

        self.frame = frame

    def run(self):
        pos = True
        while pos:
            if self.frame.pos().x() == 50 and self.frame.pos().y() == 180:
                print('Complete')
            else:
                print('Error')

            time.sleep(0.01)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.InitWindow()

        self.thread = Thread(self.frame)
        self.thread.start()

    def InitWindow(self):
        self.resize(500, 500)

        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.frame.resize(100, 100)
        self.frame.move(50, 180)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: black')
        self.x, self.y = self.frame.pos().x(), self.frame.pos().y()

        self.text = "x: {0},  y: {1}".format(self.x, self.y)
        self.label = QLabel(self.text, self)
        self.label.setGeometry(50, 0, 100, 100)

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_Down:
            self.y += 10
        elif e.key() == Qt.Key_Up:
            self.y -= 10
        elif e.key() == Qt.Key_Right:
            self.x += 10
        elif e.key() == Qt.Key_Left:
            self.x -= 10

        self.frame.move(self.x, self.y)
        self.text = "x: {0},  y: {1}".format(self.x, self.y)
        self.label.setText(self.text)
```

---

**PS.**

Другой способ, более правильный, алгоритма через поток это заведение двух сигналов:

- Из `Window` в `Thread` при изменении положения `self.frame` в `keyPressEvent`
- Из `Thread` в `Window` отсылать сигнал с результатом проверки: `Complete` / `Error`

Сигналы нужно подключать к методам, т.е. еще в обоих объектах нужно будет завести методы, что будут вызываться на те новые сигналы

Comment: Добрай день @gil9red . 
Скажите пожалуйста, разве использование `self.frame` основного GUI 
в потоке `self.frame.pos().x()` не потокобезопасно? 
Мне кажется, что в поток надо передавать `self.x`, `self.y`

Comment: @S.Nick, думаю, это работает потому что есть GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). А так, как я писал в `PS.` лучше сигналами делать. Тогда уж сигналом из `Window` можно будет передавать значения `self.x, self.y`

Comment: с сигналами все понятно. Посмотрите пожалуйста ваш ответ измененный мною.

Answer (score 1):

Мне показалось, что так будет потокобезопаснее:

```
#import time
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QFrame, QApplication, QLabel


class Thread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, x, y):                       #frame):
        super().__init__()

#        self.frame = frame
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def run(self):
        pos = True
        while pos:
#            if self.frame.pos().x() == 50 and self.frame.pos().y() == 180:
            if self.x == 50 and self.y == 180:
                print('Complete')
            else:
                print('Error')

            self.msleep(1000)    # time.sleep(1)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.InitWindow()

        self.thread = Thread(self.x, self.y)                  #(self.frame)
        self.thread.start()

    def InitWindow(self):
        self.resize(500, 500)

        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.frame.resize(100, 100)
        self.frame.move(50, 180)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: black')
        self.x, self.y = self.frame.pos().x(), self.frame.pos().y()

        self.text = "x: {0},  y: {1}".format(self.x, self.y)
        self.label = QLabel(self.text, self)
        self.label.setGeometry(250, 200, 100, 100)

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_Down:
            self.y += 10
        elif e.key() == Qt.Key_Up:
            self.y -= 10
        elif e.key() == Qt.Key_Right:
            self.x += 10
        elif e.key() == Qt.Key_Left:
            self.x -= 10

        self.frame.move(self.x, self.y)
        self.text = "x: {0},  y: {1}".format(self.x, self.y)
        self.label.setText(self.text)

        self.thread.x = self.x                                  # +++
        self.thread.y = self.y                                  # +++

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Тоже сойдет, но это тоже яйцо, но в профиль :) По хорошему, к объекту из одного потока обращаться к объекту из другого объекта небезопасно :) Безопасно будет через сигналы-слоты, общую память, сокеты и т.п. Кст, вы знали, что то, что в `run` выполняется это код в другом потоке, а вот код в `__init__` выполняется в том потоке, где объект потока был создан