# Проблема с QThreadPool или QThread в PyQt, или же как взаимодействуют объекты в PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qthread, pyqt6

Всем привет, есть несколько вопросов!

***Сразу предисловие, я пытаюсь разобраться в этом фреймворке и пока плохо ориентируюсь, если есть подобные темы решения данной проблемы, пожалуйста киньте ссылку. Весь код в конце поста!***

1. Столкнулся с проблемой в PyQT в использовании QThread объекта, пытаюсь в поток передать метод класса главного окна по скачиванию видео "self.download", и решил это сделать через передачу ссылки на сам объект "main_window\self", есть подозрение что оно падает на моменте апдейта элемента "textEdit".
2. Также пытался воспользоваться QthreadPool, но проблема не решилась.
3. Почему в PyQT нет аналогии с объектом "Concurrent" как в C++? Там есть метод "map\mapper" по аналогии как в объекте "Pool" метод "map", который сам управляется, нам лишь нужно в этот метод передавать метод и коллекцию для исполнения.

**Что ожидаю от выполнения кода**: что нажимая на кнопку "Download", будет запускать метод "run_multi_download", в котором будет создаваться новый поток на каждую ссылку и дергать метод класса главного окна "self.download". И в конечном счете после завершения скачивания нам нужно асинхронно апдейтить элемент главного окна, что видео скачено.

**Проблема**: как по мне, при попытке обновить элемент, то есть добавить текст, происходит падение в отдельном потоке хоть и передаю ссылку на сам объект основного потока. Не знаю, прав ли я, и как это решить. Ну и собственно ловлю в консоле это "Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)".

**П.С.**: я уже читал кучу тем с проблемой и переписку разрабов данного фрейма, что не получится словить "тихое падение" или же "uncaught\unhandled exception" для отдельных потоков или же слотов.

Да я тут много всякого разного экспериментировал с кодом, поэтому много не нужного кода, почищу когда найду проблему.

**main.py**

```
import sys
import traceback
# from exception_handler import pyqt_catch_exception_slot, log_uncaught_exceptions
from youtube_thread import YouTubeThread
from pytube import YouTube
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets,  QtCore, uic
from PyQt6.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QThreadPool
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMainWindow


def excepthook(type_, value, traceback_):
    traceback.print_exception(type_, value, traceback_)
    QtCore.qFatal('')


class YouTubeInstance:
    def __init__(self):
        self.youtube = YouTube
        self.path = None

    def set_path(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def download_file(self, url):
        local_yt = self.youtube(url=url)
        local_yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().download(self.path)
        return f'Video \"{local_yt.title}\" has been downloaded successfully!'


class YouTubeMultiDownloader(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('YTMultiDownloader_3.ui', self)
        self.ui.folder_opt.setTextMargins(20, 0, 0, 0)
        self.urls = None
        self.path = None
        # self.thread_pool = QThreadPool()
        # self.youtube = YouYouTubeInstance()
        self.youtube = YouTube
        self.yt_thread = YouTubeThread

        # buttons connection with backend
        self.ui.folder_btn.clicked.connect(self.get_directory)
        self.ui.download_btn.clicked.connect(self.run_multi_downloads)

    def _get_urls_from_form(self):
        self.urls = self.ui.youtube_urls.toPlainText().split('\n')

    def get_directory(self):
        path_to_dir = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select folder"))
        self.path = path_to_dir
        # self.youtube.set_path(path_to_dir)
        self.ui.folder_opt.setText(path_to_dir)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def download_file(self, url):
        local_yt = self.youtube(url=url)
        local_yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().download(self.path)
        resp_text = f'Video \"{local_yt.title}\" has been downloaded successfully!'
        self.ui.youtube_opt.setText(resp_text)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run_multi_downloads(self):
        self.ui.youtube_urls.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui.download_btn.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui.folder_btn.setEnabled(False)
        self._get_urls_from_form()

        for url in self.urls:
            yt_thread = self.yt_thread(main_window=self, url=url)
            yt_thread.start()
            # self.thread_pool.start(lambda: self.download_file(url))
            # print(self.thread_pool.activeThreadCount())

        # self.ui.youtube_opt.setText('\n'.join(self.pool(self._get_urls_from_form()).map(self.youtube.download_file, self.urls)))

        self.ui.youtube_urls.setEnabled(True)
        self.ui.download_btn.setEnabled(True)
        self.ui.folder_btn.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.excepthook = excepthook
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = YouTubeMultiDownloader()
    application.show()
    app.exec()
    # sys.exit(app.exec())

'''
pyvid = ['https://youtu.be/qn-lo0AXy5s', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVdY83s9TQQ']
download(pyvid[0])
'''
```

**thread.py**

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore


class YouTubeThread(QtCore.QThread):
    any_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, main_window, url):
        super().__init__()
        self.app = main_window
        self.url = url

    def run(self):
        self.app.download_file(url=self.url)
```

**YTMultiDownloader_3.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>main_window</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="main_window">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>990</width>
    <height>648</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>990</width>
    <height>648</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>990</width>
    <height>648</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>YouTubeMultiDownloader</string>
  </property>
  <property name="windowIcon">
   <iconset>
    <normaloff>yt.png</normaloff>yt.png</iconset>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(234, 234, 234);</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="central_widget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="folder_btn">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>770</x>
      <y>80</y>
      <width>180</width>
      <height>60</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="toolTip">
     <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;Folder to download all files.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="whatsThis">
     <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 30;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: 75 14pt &quot;Leelawadee UI&quot;;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(203, 0, 0);
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Select folder</string>
    </property>
    <property name="iconSize">
     <size>
      <width>16</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </size>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="download_btn">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>400</x>
      <y>540</y>
      <width>191</width>
      <height>60</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="toolTip">
     <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;Button to start download files.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="whatsThis">
     <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 30;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: 75 14pt &quot;Leelawadee UI&quot;;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(203, 0, 0);
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Download</string>
    </property>
    <property name="iconSize">
     <size>
      <width>16</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </size>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="folder_opt">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>80</y>
      <width>681</width>
      <height>60</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
border: 1px solid #000000;
border-radius: 30;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
font: 75 14pt &quot;Leelawadee UI&quot;;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="readOnly">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="placeholderText">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="layoutWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>190</y>
      <width>911</width>
      <height>301</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontal_layout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QTextEdit" name="youtube_urls">
       <property name="toolTip">
        <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:12pt;&quot;&gt;Paste youtube links here!&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
font: 75 12pt &quot;Leelawadee UI&quot;;
border: 1px solid #000000;
border-radius: 15;
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
       <property name="placeholderText">
        <string>Paste youtube links here...</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
       <property name="orientation">
        <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="sizeType">
        <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
        <size>
         <width>41</width>
         <height>20</height>
        </size>
       </property>
      </spacer>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QTextEdit" name="youtube_opt">
       <property name="toolTip">
        <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="whatsThis">
        <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
font: 75 12pt &quot;Leelawadee UI&quot;;
border: 1px solid #000000;
border-radius: 15;
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
       <property name="readOnly">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
 <slots>
  <slot>choose_folder()</slot>
  <slot>run_multi_downloads()</slot>
 </slots>
</ui>
```

Comment: Нельзя взаимодействовать с виджетами в дополнительном потоке. Опубликуйте модуль `YTMultiDownloader_3.ui`

Comment: @S.Nick опубликовал, тогда как лучше сделать?

Comment: DaymaNkinG попробуйте следующее решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1200917/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-youtube-dl/1201592#1201592

Comment: @S.Nick спасибо за тред, почитал, но мне нужно понять как мне сделать так, чтобы я мог скачивать несколько видео параллельно, плюс я заметил что вы использовали в примере того поста объект QObject и внутри него threading.Thread, но зачем? И как мне все же передавать результат того что видео скачалось в элемент textEdit главного виджета асинхронно?

Comment: @S.Nick почитал несколько разных статей про slot's\signal's, и пришел к выводу из вашего ответа из другого треда, что я могу из потока возвращать посредством сигнала. Тред -> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1056690/qthread-связь-окна-с-потоком

Comment: DaymaNkinG да, это так. О Signals & Slots читаем https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: @S.Nick добрый день, мне удалось это сделать! Спасибо за подсказки)

Comment: DaymaNkinG пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда мы создаем кнопку на интерфейсе и в коде прописываем методом "connect", то мы связываем сигнал и слот. Сигналом будет выступать событие, то есть когда мы нажимаем на кнопку, то будет происходить вызов этого сигнала. И сигнал дальше дергает слот, который мы соединили методом "connect". В метод "connect" всегда прокидывают аргумент в виде метода класса, который будет дергаться когда придет сигнал.

[image: Механизм работы сигналов и слотов]

Оно аналогично работает как callbacks просто в python, то есть когда мы объявили сначала первую функцию, и когда объявляем вторую функцию, и во второй функции вызываем первую:

```
def first():
    pass

def second():
    return first()
```

То сигналом для первой функции выступает вторая функция, а слотом выступает собственно сама первая функция.

Также стоит учитывать, что сигналы бывают разные. Мы можем не прокидывать в сигнал какую-либо сигнатуру, а сам метод находящийся в слоте не будет ожидать каких-либо аргументов на вход. Либо, если нам нужно прокинуть какие-то данные, то мы должны в pyqtSignal указать сигнатуру в виде типа данных, которые мы ожидаем прокинуть.

Про кастомные сигналы не стоит забывать так как мы захотим модифицировать логику работы нашей программы. Можно создавать несколько разных сигналов в одном объекте, чтобы на разную логику отправлялись разные сигналы с разными данными. И не стоит забывать, что мы также можем передать несколько типов сигнатур в один сигнал, но логику через сигналы все же стоит разграничивать, это считается хороший тоном.

---

Повторюсь! Моя задача состояла в том, чтобы запустить на каждую ссылку  отдельный поток и скачать видео\аудио с ютуба, после чего мне необходимо было понять что видео\аудио было скачено, и нужно было как-то вернуть информацию об завершении этого действия. Собственно тут сработал один и единственно верный механизм(который я описал выше), который существует в Qt. Подсказал **S.Nick** - [Документация по Signals & Slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html). Также есть и видос на эту тему - [нажать сюда](https://youtu.be/HYQcagSG0is).

Собственно, чтобы воплотить мою идею, мне надо было создать как атрибут класса pyqtSignal с той сигнатурой, которую я буду передавать обратно в главное окно. Дальше когда видео\аудио скачивалось мне нужно было написать такой код:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore
from pytube import YouTube


class YouTubeThread(QtCore.QThread):

    thread_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.youtube = YouTube
        self.url = None
        self.path = None
        self.is_video = None

    def __download_video(self) -> None:
        local_yt = self.youtube(url=self.url)
        local_yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().download(self.path)
        self.thread_signal.emit(f'Video \"{local_yt.title}\" has been downloaded successfully!')

    def __download_audio(self) -> None:
        local_yt = self.youtube(url=self.url)
        local_yt.streams.get_audio_only().download(self.path)
        self.thread_signal.emit(f'Audio \"{local_yt.title}\" has been downloaded successfully!')

    def init_args(self, url: str, path: str = None, video: bool = True) -> None:
        self.url = url
        self.path = path
        self.is_video = video

    def run(self) -> None:
        if self.is_video:
            self.__download_video()
        else:
            self.__download_audio()
```

То есть после скачивания, я обращался к сигналу по средством метода "emit", и передавал данные в вызванный метод, которые мне надо было передать в главное окно программы для обновления текстового элемента.

---

***Есть также отдельные треды, по схожей теме:***

1. [Прогресс загрузки youtube-dl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1200917/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-youtube-dl/1201592#1201592)
2. [QThread, связь окна с потоком](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1056690/qthread-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC)